# Running into issue 'Type Location is missing the following properties from type ...'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to extend the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) [interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0326534a2a6c361f5334a66197a3cdd84cb45b6f/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L9942), but it's throwing me the error:

```
Type 'Location<{ modal?: boolean | undefined; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'ILocation': ancestorOrigins, host, hostname, href, and 6 more
```

I'm trying to instantiate as:

```
interface ILocation extends Location {
  state?: {
    modal?: boolean
  }
}

const location: ILocation = useLocation();
```

My question is, what is the point of extending `Location`, if it requires me to list all the properties of `Location` in `ILocation`? Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of inheritance?

Comment: What Location interface? From where?

Comment: @IanKemp I am extending `interface Location..` from `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:9906`

Comment: @faithfull It is not my `Location` interface, it is typescript's. I was under the impression that I could extend it, name it as `ILocation` and just define it as I have in the OP. I've tried doing something like `const location: Location<ILocation> = useLocation();`, where `ILocation` is defined the same, as `interface ILocation { state?: { modal?: boolean } }`, but that threw the error `Type Location is not generic`.

Comment: It would also hope if you showed us what `useLocation` is doing. I'd guess that's the source of your problem.

Comment: `useLocation` is the hook from [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/hooks.md), it's not my hook.

Comment: Figured it out. I was supposed to extend location from `import { Location } from "history";`. Thank you.